How can I round up a timestamp to the nearest 5 minutes in MySQL?
For example,
2024-09-09 13:00:00 will be 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:00:50 will be 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:01:00 will be 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:04:00 will be 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:04:59 will be 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:05:00 will be 2024-09-09 13:10:00

The answers I find are generally about rounding down, but I want to round up.
Thanks
I tried to use various methods, and adapt the round down to round up, but nothing worked.

SELECT original_ts, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(original_ts) + 300) DIV 300) * 300) rounded_ts
FROM table_name;

300 is the number of seconds in a 5-minute interval.

This does indeed match my expected results but actually, I was wrong. 13:00:00 should yield 13:00:00 not 13:05:00. Thank you very much.

@MartinCubitt Remove + 300 simply.. or replace it with + 299 (depends on your precise task).

Here is the query that will round up a DATETIME to the next 5-minute mark:
    SELECT 
    -- Add 4 minutes and 59 seconds to the original time to round up
    DATE_ADD(DATE(datetime_column), 
        INTERVAL (FLOOR((HOUR(datetime_column) * 60 + MINUTE(datetime_column) + 4) / 5) * 5) MINUTE) 
    AS rounded_datetime
FROM 
    your_table;

Explanation:

HOUR(datetime_column) * 60 + MINUTE(datetime_column): This converts the hour and minute portion of the datetime to total minutes.
+ 4: Adds 4 minutes so that any time within a 5-minute interval will round up to the next interval.
FLOOR((minutes + 4) / 5) * 5: Divides the total minutes by 5 to find the nearest 5-minute interval, then rounds down using FLOOR().
DATE_ADD(): Adds the calculated number of minutes to the date.

Example Output:
2024-09-09 13:00:00 becomes 2024-09-09 13:05:00
2024-09-09 13:00:50 becomes 2024-09-09 13:05:00

Thank you for your detailed solution, I really appreciate the clarity you gave.
I noticed the results your solution gave do not match my expected results, but that could be more about my expected results being wrong.
Eg 13:00:00 gives 13:00:00 but my expected results say 13:05:00. But I think this is down to my expected results. 13:00:00 is correct.
Thanks again!

For others trying to see how the 2 queries differ, here is a query with both and the results.
select origtime,
DATE_ADD(DATE(origtime), 
        INTERVAL (FLOOR((HOUR(origtime) * 60 + MINUTE(origtime) + 4) / 5) * 5) MINUTE) 
    AS ans1,
FROM_UNIXTIME(((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(origtime) + 300) DIV 300) * 300) ans2
from 
(select '2024-09-09 13:00:00' origtime union 
select '2024-09-09 13:00:50' union 
select '2024-09-09 13:01:00' union 
select '2024-09-09 13:04:00' union 
select '2024-09-09 13:04:59' union
select '2024-09-09 13:05:00'
) s;

origtime             ans1                    ans2
2024-09-09 13:00:00  2024-09-09 13:00:00.0  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0
2024-09-09 13:00:50  2024-09-09 13:00:00.0  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0
2024-09-09 13:01:00  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0
2024-09-09 13:04:00  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0
2024-09-09 13:04:59  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0
2024-09-09 13:05:00  2024-09-09 13:05:00.0  2024-09-09 13:10:00.0

